# Create Custom Table that Includes Task Mode

Tags: ms-project

I am writing a VBA macro in MS Project and trying to build a custom table.  I started by recording a macro which added the "Task Mode" column without issue.  Since "Task Mode" is not an actual field, the recorded macro errors out when I try to run it.  The task property "Manual" does not work either.  Is there some other way to add "Task Mode" programmatically?  (The statement below is the 4th column in the table.)

TableEditEx Name:="JCustomTbl", TaskTable:=False, NewFieldName:="Task Mode", Title:="Task Mode", Width:=10, Align:=0, LockFirstColumn:=True, DateFormat:=255, RowHeight:=1, AlignTitle:=1, HeaderAutoRowHeightAdjustment:=False, WrapText:=False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task Mode is a task field so presumably jCUstomTbl is a task table and therefore the TaskTable parameter should be set to True:

`TableEditEx Name:="JCustomTbl", TaskTable:=True, NewFieldName:="Task Mode", Title:="Task Mode", Width:=10, Align:=0, LockFirstColumn:=True, DateFormat:=255, RowHeight:=1, AlignTitle:=1, HeaderAutoRowHeightAdjustment:=False, WrapText:=False`

Reference: [TableEditEx method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.tableeditex)

Comment: Huh, that was easy! :-)  Thanks Rachel - you're awesome!